# Resource in MVC 4 razor

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, model-view-controller, resources

I have to print all the key value pairs from application resource file in a table format in razor view.

I'm new please help me out.

**Resource.resx:**

```
Key  | value
---------------
name  |  John
mob   | 9090909090
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get all the key value pairs from application resource file use below method:

```
public Dictionary<string,string> gtresource()
{
     System.Resources.ResourceManager RM = new System.Resources.ResourceManager("KDConsole.Resources.Resource", this.GetType().Assembly);
     Dictionary<string, string> dic = new Dictionary<string, string>();
     System.Resources.ResourceSet resourceSet = RM.GetResourceSet(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, true, true);
     foreach (System.Collections.DictionaryEntry item in resourceSet)
        {
            dic.Add(item.Key.ToString(), item.Value.ToString());
        }
     return dic;
```

}